# System plugin not working in external loaded Joomla framework

Tags: php, joomla3.0

i am loading joomla framework into external file using below code:

```
<?php
define( '_JEXEC', 1 ); 
$basepath   =   dirname(__FILE__);
define('JPATH_BASE', $basepath);
require_once( JPATH_BASE.'/includes/defines.php' );
require_once( JPATH_BASE.'/includes/framework.php' );
JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterLoad') : null;

if (!defined('JPATH_COMPONENT') or !constant('JPATH_COMPONENT')){
    define('JPATH_COMPONENT', JPATH_BASE.'/components/'.'com_zoo');
}
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$app->initialise();
```

but the problem is, when i use this code and do anything, system plugin hooks are not working.

please help.

Comment: Are you sure that the JPATH base is correct here? This file is in the top level of the joomla installation?

Comment: Yes, I can access framework easily, but onAfterInitialise function of system plugin is not being accessed

Answer (score 0):

OK so finally got the answer. i am not sure weather it is correct way to do so. I have to import system plugin and call the hook.

```
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('system');
$app->triggerEvent('onAfterInitialise');
```

This will load the plugin and call the hook.